# Why can I not use In() inside FindOptions with TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I'm currently trying to use `In()`  to add a `WHERE field IN()` clause to my SQL query.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
this.repository.find({
  where: {
    id: In(['uuid-1', 'uuid-2']),
  },
  ...options,
  withDeleted: false,
});
```

I get a TypeScript error that says:

```
Type '{ id: FindOperator<string[]>; }' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhere<Entity> | FindOptionsWhere<Entity>[]'.
  Types of property 'field' are incompatible.
    Type 'FindOperator<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsWhereProperty<NonNullable<Entity["id"]>>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be [a bug with TypeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9508).

A temporary workaround ended up being to cast the options passed to `Repository.find()` like so:

```
const records = await this.repository.find({
  where: {
    id: In(['uuid-1', 'uuid-2']),
  } as FindOptionsWhere<Entity>,
  ...options
  withDeleted: false,
});
```